# How can I access the HttpServerUtility instance in ASP.NET MVC controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can I access the HttpServerUtility instance in ASP.NET MVC controller?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

"this.httpContext.Server" is a reference to HttpServerUtilityBase, the abstract class wrapper that's a part of the System.Web.Abstractions DLL.  You can also do:

```
HttpContext.Current.Server
```

To directly access the "old-school" way.  Also you can get an instance of the base class using the wrapper by doing the following:

```
new HttpServerUtilityWrapper(HttpContext.Current.Server)
```

The wrapper class inherits from httpServerUtilityBase