# How can I access to HttpServerUtility instance?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on my ASP.NET MVC 5 project.

I need to access  the `HttpServerUtility` instance. I tried it this way:

`this.Server`

But I get `HttpServerUtilityBase`. I tried this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4206969/how-can-i-access-the-httpserverutility-instance-in-asp-net-mvc-controller), but it didn't help me.

How can I access to `HttpServerUtility` instance?

Comment: You didn't get an [HttpServerUtilityBase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutilitybase(v=vs.110).aspx) because that type is *abstract*. Nothing can create one. What you got is something *derived* from that class. What makes you believe that you specifically need to obtain `HttpServerUtility`?

Comment: Ia am working on GIS project.I Have function that have a parameter of type HttpServerUtility.

Comment: And can you not change the function? (by far the more sensible approach)

Comment: Agree with @Damien_The_Unbeliever. If you can change it, would be best. MVC provides the *Base classes for this kind of thing, since they are not tightly coupled to the ASP.NET pipeline. Would be even better if you could avoid passing these objects around altogether.